# как продублировать все элементы динамического массива (вектора) в C++?

Tags: c++, vector

Имеется вектор с целыми числами, необходимо продублировать каждый из его элементов. Например:

> исходный вектор: 12 56 -7 89 4 0 11 -6;
>
> результат: 12 12 56 56 -7 -7 89 89 4 4 0 0 11 11 -6 -6.

Я решил воспользоваться методом `insert()`, предварительно объявив итератор. Но программа выдает ошибку. Насколько я знаю, метод `insert(p, x)` вставляет значение `x` ПЕРЕД элементом, на который указывает итератор `p` и возвращает итератор на вставленный элемент, поэтому я сделал шаг `p + 2` чтобы добраться до следующего элемента, а иначе, при использовании обычного инкремента, итератор вставал бы на элемент, который уже был продублирован. Возможно, я неправильно понимаю, как работает метод `insert()` и как функционируют итераторы.

Вот цикл, который должен дублировать элементы вектора:

```
for (auto p = ivec.begin(); p != ivec.end();)
{


    ivec.insert(p, *p);
    p + 2;


}
```

`ivec` - вектор,
`p` - итератор

Вывод программы:

> free(): invalid pointer
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: `p + 2` - выражение, которое ничего не делает. Что вы им хотели сказать?

Comment: хотел сдвинуть итератор на две позиции вперед, ясно, что нужно было написать p = p + 2 или p += 2, но не в этом главная ошибка, программа все равно не работает.

Comment: Поздно сдвигать итератор, когда он уже разрушен. Вы же сами написали: "возвращает итератор на вставленный элемент". Так почему же вы игнорируете возвращенное значение?

Comment: эффективнее создать новый вектор с размером вдвое больше исходного, и заполнять его, а вообще для такой задачи лучше подойдет линейный список

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert                                                                                                       "Вызывает реаллокацию если новый size() больше, чем старый capacity(). 
Если новый size() больше, чем capacity(), все итераторы и указатели становятся нерабочими. В противном случае, нерабочими становятся только итераторы и указатели на элементы, идущие после вставленных. "                                              Может, перед вставкой элементов стоит сначала размер увеличить?

Answer (score 8):

Влезу и я со своими 5 копейками. При таком варианте у вас будет `O(N^2)` перемещений элементов, что не слишком хорошо. Я бы создал новый вектор удвоенного размера и простым циклом переписал все элементы, т.е. выполнив операцию за `O(N)`. Потом можно просто выполнить перемещение данных. Примерно так

```
void dbl(vector<int>&v)
{
    vector<int> n;
    n.reserve(v.size()*2);
    for(auto i: v) { n.push_back(i); n.push_back(i); }
    v.swap(n);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    for(auto i: v) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;
    dbl(v);
    for(auto i: v) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;

}
```

**Update**

Как обычно, проведем эксперимент :) Итак, три версии - моя, AR Hovsepyan, со вставкой. Для `int` и тормознутого класса (тормознутость имитируется небольшой задержкой). Так как задержка тормозит конкретно, для `int` - 100000 элементов, для тормозов - 1000. Полный код эксперимента приведен ниже. Результаты для 100000 `int`:

```
Мой код      533 mks
Код ARH      419 mks
Вставка   640601 mks
```

Для тормозов в 1 нс :)

```
Мой код      6826 mks
Код ARH     40797 mks
Вставка   1418118 mks
```

В общем, что и требовалось доказать...

Полный код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void dblHW(vector<T>&v)
{
    vector<T> n;
    n.reserve(v.size()*2);
    for(auto i: v) { n.push_back(i); n.push_back(i); }
    v.swap(n);
}


template<typename T>
void dblAR(vector<T>& v)
{
    vector<T> t(v.size() * 2);
    int j = 0;
    for(T i : v) {
        t[j] = t[j + 1] = i;
        j += 2;
    }
    v.swap(t);
}

template<typename T>
void dblIns(vector<T>& v)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i+=2)
        v.insert(v.begin()+i,v[i]);
}

class Tormoz
{
    #define  delay  this_thread::sleep_for(1ns)
public:
    Tormoz(int i = 0):i(i) { delay; }
    ~Tormoz() { delay; }
    Tormoz& operator = (const Tormoz& t) { i = t.i; delay; return *this; }
    Tormoz(const Tormoz& t) : i(t.i) { delay; }
    Tormoz(Tormoz&& t) : i(t.i) { delay; }

    int i;
};

bool operator == (const Tormoz& a, const Tormoz& b)
{
    return a.i == b.i;
}

class muTimer
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    bool active = false;
    Clock::duration   duration_;
    Clock::time_point start_ = Clock::now(), stop_ = Clock::now();

    muTimer(const muTimer&)             = delete;
    muTimer& operator=(const muTimer&)  = delete;
public:
    using ns       = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using mks      = std::chrono::microseconds;
    using ms       = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    muTimer() { reset(); start(); }
    ~muTimer() = default;
    muTimer& reset()
    {
        duration_ = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
        active    = false;
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& start()
    {
        if (!active)
        {
            start_ = Clock::now();
            active = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& stop()
    {
        if (active)
        {
            stop_      = Clock::now();
            duration_ += stop_ - start_;
            active     = false;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename T = mks>
        unsigned long long duration()
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned long long>
            (std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(stop_-start_).count());
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        vector<int> a;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
            a.push_back(rand());
        vector<int> b = a, c = a;

        //for(int i : a) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;

        {
            muTimer m;
            dblHW(a);
            m.stop();
            cout << "HW:  " << m.duration() << " mks\n";
        }
        {
            muTimer m;
            dblAR(b);
            m.stop();
            cout << "ARH: " << m.duration() << " mks\n";
        }
        {
            muTimer m;
            dblIns(c);
            m.stop();
            cout << "Ins:  " << m.duration() << " mks\n";
        }

        assert(a == b && b == c);
    }

    {
        vector<Tormoz> a;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            a.push_back(rand());
        vector<Tormoz> b = a, c = a;

        //for(int i : a) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;

        {
            muTimer m;
            dblHW(a);
            m.stop();
            cout << "HW:  " << m.duration() << " mks\n";
        }
        {
            muTimer m;
            dblAR(b);
            m.stop();
            cout << "ARH: " << m.duration() << " mks\n";
        }
        {
            muTimer m;
            dblIns(c);
            m.stop();
            cout << "Ins:  " << m.duration() << " mks\n";
        }

        assert(a == b && b == c);
    }

}
```

Comment: Harry, однако здравствуйте!  А не лучше инициализация для   vector<int> n(v.size()*2), чем    столько раз вызовать  push_back(i)?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А чем именно инициализировать? А в плане присвоения или `push_back` - разница, как мне кажется, невелика, но может стать таковой при объектах с затратной инициализацией...

Comment: Тебе ещё версия на замер) Хотя, кажется у меня за счёт пачки вызовов конструктора в resize будет так себе результат на тормозном классе.

Comment: @Qwertiy При тех же условиях по усреднению 5 тестов дала 455 и примерно 6700. Неплохо.

Comment: @Harry, это для интов? А чего в табличку не добавил? А, всё, вижу... 6700 - быстрее твоего? Почему так? Вроде у тебя не должно быть лишних конструкторов? А если emplace_back вместо push_back попробуешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да можно, только времени не хватает... рабочий день все-таки :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/ - "Iterator validity"

```
p = ivec.insert(p, *p);
```

Comment: Мееееееееееедленно...

Answer (score 0):

Предложу другой вариант(без вызовов функций) ответа `Harry`

```
void dbl(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::vector<int> t(v.size() * 2);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i : v) {
        t[j] = t[j + 1] = i;
        j += 2;
    }
    v.swap(t);
}
```

P.S. А если вы часто пользуетесь вставками и удалением, то  `std::list` кандидат получше вектора

Comment: См. мой дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/RCUR7N

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> void duplicate(vector <T> &v)
{
  size_t n = v.size();
  v.resize(n << 1);

  for (size_t q=n-1; ~q; --q)
  {
    v[(q<<1)|1] = v[q];
    v[q<<1] = move(v[q]); // should work for 0
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
  for(auto i: v) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;
  duplicate(v);
  for(auto i: v) cout << i << "  "; cout << endl;
}
```